# convert tweepy stream data to dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tweepy

Hello I have been trying to convert the streaming dict data from tweepy to dataframe but I get the error:
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'"

here is my code:

```
class TwitterListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

     def on_data(self, raw_data):

        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        print(data)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data["text"])
        df

        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        
        if status_code == 420:
        #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":

    myStreamListener = TwitterListener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener=myStreamListener)

    myStream.filter(track= 'python')
```

the raw_data basically prints raw tweet data in dict.

Please help me to acheive a appending dataframe.

Comment: Your class doesn't seem to be formatted properly here. What's the full traceback?

Comment: @Harmon758 I have edited the format. Please check now.

Comment: Again, what's the full traceback? Also, the body of the `if` statement is still improperly indented.